# A `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected` Error when adding a routerLink in the submit button for log in

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

In Angular 4 form, I add a button like this:

```
<button 
   [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" 
   class="btn btn-primary" 
   type="submit" 
   routerLink='/dashboard'>
</button>`
```

When I click the button, it get an error **"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"**, but if I *delete* the `routerLink` property, the error will disappear. Can you tell me why this happened ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. If you have any other button in your form just replace type="submit" with type="button". It'll resolve your issue.

Comment: But I need to use this button to submit my form for logging in. If I change the type to "button", the login function does not work...

Comment: Removing `Submit` in forms isn't recommended unless you want a different `click` action...